# Transformation of random variable and distribution function

Tags: probability, statistics

I have task
"Let X by random varaible with exponential distribution and parameter $\lambda$"
We have to find distribution function of random variable $Y=e^x$

My solution is quite easy

$1) F_{y}(Y) = P( y <= Y ) = P(y <= e^x ) = P( ln(y) <= x )$ as the last step i used inversion function on both side ( ln )

2) $P(ln(y) <= x ) = 1 - P( x <= ln(y) = 1 - F_{x}(ln(y))$
And we know that distribution function of x is exponential distribution function so it should be

$F_{y} = 1 - 1-e^{-\lambda x} = 1 - 1 - e^{-\lambda ln(y)}$

But i am not sure if i can assume, that when i have x in function its automaticly distribution function of X.

Did i make mistake or is this way correct?

Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first step is correct, but I do not agree with the second part of your answer.

\begin{align*}
F_Y(y) & = P(Y \leq y) \\
& = P( \exp(X) \leq y ) \\
& = P( X \leq \log y) \\
& = F_X(\log y) \\
& = 1 - \exp \left( - \lambda \log y \right) \\
& = 1 - y^{-\lambda}
\end{align*}

Comment: what do u mean by "exp"?

Comment: It is the exponential, same as using $e$.

Comment: Why did you use $F_{Y}(y)$ instead of $F_{y}(Y) $?

Comment: Standard notation is to use capital $Y$ for the random variable, and lower case $y$ for the value taken. In which case the function $F_Y$ denotes that it is the distribution function of $Y$, whilst the argument is the value taken, eg. $y$. So in all $F_Y(y)$.

Comment: oh! i know about the notation just thought it should be other way around. It makes sense. Thanks